# Unexpected tIDENTIFIER

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a simple user authentication system for my website, but I keep getting this error message:

> C:/Users/Chris/Documents/DePaul/IT 231/chocolate/app/controllers/simplelogin_controller.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' ...name(name_out) redirect_to maintenance_chkmaintenance_p... ... ^ C:/Users/Chris/Documents/DePaul/IT 231/chocolate/app/controllers/simplelogin_controller.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end end end end ^

Here is my controller:

```
Class SimpleloginController < ApplicationController  
  def namein    

  end

  def transmain  
    @familyname_out = params[:family_name_in] #textbox name from the input file 
    name_out  = params[:family_name_in]   
    if found = Family.find_by_name(name_out)   
      redirect_to maintenance_chkmaintenance_path :notice => "Logged in successfully" 
    else  
      redirect_to simplelogin_namein_path :notice => "Invalid login. Try again" 
    end    
  end 
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Class SimpleloginController < ApplicationController  
  def namein    

  end

  def transmain  
    @familyname_out = params[:family_name_in] #textbox name from the input file 
    name_out  = params[:family_name_in]   
    if found = Family.find_by_name(name_out)   
      redirect_to maintenance_chkmaintenance_path, :notice => "Logged in successfully" 
    else  
      redirect_to simplelogin_namein_path, :notice => "Invalid login. Try again" 
    end    
  end 
end
```

Problem in  `redirect_to maintenance_chkmaintenance_path, :notice => "Logged in successfully"`

You are not giving (comma) so syntax error is occured

Answer (score 2):

In your code the syntax for redirect to is

```
redirect_to YOUR_PATH :notice => "YOUR NOTICE"
```

Here a comma ',' is missing before `:notice`

So, try with this.

```
redirect_to YOUR_PATH, :notice => "YOUR NOTICE"
```

Comment: don't just fix the problem, tell him what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma in your `redirect_to` calls

```
redirect_to maintenance_chkmaintenance_path :notice => "Logged in successfully" 
...
redirect_to simplelogin_namein_path :notice => "Invalid login. Try again"
```

should be

```
redirect_to maintenance_chkmaintenance_path, :notice => "Logged in successfully" 
...
redirect_to simplelogin_namein_path, :notice => "Invalid login. Try again"
```