# What is an "Unexpected IDENTIFIER"?

Tags: ruby

I sometimes get syntax errors just like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215525/unexpected-tidentifier), where Ruby raises an error about an "unexpected IDENTIFIER". Fixing the syntax of the code seems to resolve the issue, but leaves me puzzled as to what was responsible for the error in the first place.

My hope is that if I know what a tIDENTIFIER actually is, I could look for it in my syntax and remove it directly.

Comment: Maybe this article can clarify things a little: http://robdodson.me/syntax-error-unexpected-tidentifier/

Comment: Token identifier found where one was not expected.  Probably due to a line ending not being there or a missing delimiter of some kind, perhaps a comma.  Presumably, you will not want to remove the token, just fix the syntax, which you state you are already doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tIDENTIFIER` is an *identifier token*. An identifier is a bit of text, like a variable or function name. In Ruby, an identifier has to start with a letter or underscore, and can then have more letters, underscores or numbers.

As an example: "main", "puts", "String" and "x2" are all identifiers. "!!", "12412", "(" and "return" are not.

To put the error message in other words: Ruby found a variable, class or method name in a place where it didn't expect it. You probably don't want to remove it: it's more likely that you just forgot something, like the comma in the example you linked.

Comment: Thanks for your clear and concise answer! I would accept this immediately, but I am afraid that doing so may be poor form in StackOverflow (as it might discourage other people from their own answers). I'll wait for a few days before choosing the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Token identifier found where one was not expected. Probably due to a line ending not being there or a missing delimiter of some kind, perhaps a comma. Presumably, you will not want to remove the token, just fix the syntax, which you state you are already doing.

See the file [parse.y](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L802-L805) for definitive details on these.

Specifically shown:

```
%token <id>   tIDENTIFIER tFID tGVAR tIVAR tCONSTANT tCVAR tLABEL
%token <node> tINTEGER tFLOAT tRATIONAL tIMAGINARY tSTRING_CONTENT tCHAR
%token <node> tNTH_REF tBACK_REF
%token <num>  tREGEXP_END
```